# What is the physics behind shake flashlights?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

What is the physics behind [shake flashlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanically_powered_flashlight)? From what I have read and from what I have seen when I tore one apart is that it is simply a magnet, coiled wire, a capacitor, and a light bulb. Mechanically it appears that by shaking the unit you are forcing a magnet to go through the center of the coiled wire.

What I do not understand is how this would power a light bulb. What is the physics behind this phenomenon. Both specifically in this situation, and even generally, how would a magnet generate power?

Comment: I think the answer is already in the wiki you linked, at the second paragraph of Shake Type Design. A basic search on the terms found there should turn up what you need.

Comment: "I do not understand is how this would power a light bulb" - it won't. It will power a LED, which requires much less energy to create the same light output.

Comment: Induction is fun.  Even I know this one, and I have never formally studied physics.

Comment: it's weirdly enough the same physics as behind gravity lights, induction

Comment: On a very irrelevant note, there's something heart-warming in seeing this question having >1k views in a matter of hours.

Comment: @PeteKirkham pedantically speaking, it also would power a light bulb.

Comment: It is worth noting that not all "shake flashlights" actually worked this way, there were quite a number of "fake" ones that simply had a button battery hidden inside - the shaking did nothing (except for amuse the scammers, probably).

Comment: Basically all power generators are just magnets moving in front of electrons. The only difference is how you convince the magnet to move.

Comment: @BradC I had one:  a dummy coil not connected to anything, a moving "magnet" that's just a lump of metal, and a 2032 coin cell or two rather than something rechargeable.

Answer (score 25):

The physics you are looking for is electromagnetic induction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction#Electrical_generator)
When you move a permanent magnet relative to a conductor (the copper wire), the magnetic field of the magnet influences the electrons in the copper, creating a current. Really, the energy that you put in to the system by shaking the flashlight is converted to electricity. This is how electrical generators work.

Comment: Fun (related) electromagnetic induction experiment/ party trick. Get a meter or so of copper plumbing pipe and one of those super-strong Neodymium magnets. Hold the pipe vertically. Drop the magnet into the pipe. And wait. And wait... eventually, it will come out of the other end, but it's clearly not falling at the usual rate!

Comment: Or take two large neodymium magnets with holes in the center, get a long wooden dowel.  Have one magnet at the bottom, one at the top of the dowel.  Have the magnets oriented so the bottom and the top will attract when they are close enough to each other.    Release the top magnet (be sure to be wearing safety goggles when doing this)

Comment: @NZKshatriya That sounds like a good way to shatter some neodymium magnets.

Comment: Here's a video of what @nigel222 was talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E97CYWlALEs

Comment: @Shufflepants  Yup, and produce a lot of sparks (when done in the dark)

Answer (score 20):

[Koldrakan’s answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/326062) explains how the energy is generated. But you might be confused as to why the bulb keeps glowing for some time rather than the light itself fluctuating with the shake.

If you didn’t already know this, that's due to the capacitor. A capacitor can store energy in the form of charge. When you shake it the electric energy generated gets stored in the capacitor. The circuit is designed in a way that rectifies the AC generated into DC. This DC charges the capacitor and then when you stop shaking it, the capacitor discharges automatically. The DC from the discharging capacitor powers the light bulb.

Comment: I've owned a shake torch with a battery as well which would be charged up. This possibly lengthens the time it will shine for.

Comment: By "energy in the form of charge" I think (hope) you mean "energy in an electric field created by separating opposing charges"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes! Indeed I meant charge separation. I couldn't put it into better words! I'll make the clarification soon. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

An important point not yet mentioned is that if electrical energy were not taken from the coil, each shake would add kinetic energy to the magnet as it was accelerated to match the velocity of the flashlight; after the flashlight stops, the sliding magnet would then continue until it reached its end of travel, whereupon the magnet would apply some of the kinetic energy back to the flashlight and possibly keep some itself as it rebounds in the opposite direction.  Current in the coil, however, will induce a magnetic force in the direction opposite the magnet's relative motion, thus reducing the amount of kinetic energy the magnet will have when it hits the end of travel.